Como incluir los registros relacionados por llaves foraneas con Entity Framework correctamente?
Estoy creando un proyecto en el que utilizo EF para el manejo de una base de datos que está en MySQL, la verdad es que apenas estoy familiarizándome con EF y no sé si lo que sucede es porque me falta algo, o porque hice algo mal. Ya tengo los modelos y cree el contexto y en teoría ya declaré la relación de uno a muchos en el context, pero no funciona como espero.
Lo que necesito, es que cuando cree el contexto y quiera yo un elemento de la tabla alumno, que me muestre el Organismo Academico al que pertenece; que en realidad sucede, pero de una manera muy curiosa.
La informacion de los alumnos se recupera bien, pero cuando accedo a la Entity de "Alumno", y quiero revisar el organismo academico al que pertenece, esta no me aparece.

Pero cuando obtengo la informacion de la tabla "OrganismoAcademico", esta si me muestra los alumnos por Organismo academico.

Y si regreso a revisar la entidad de Student, este ya me muestra el Organismo Academico al que pertenece

Este es el codigo que estoy usando para probar la recoleccion de informacion de las tablas:
ServansdtoServiceAnswerDto servansdto;
try
{   
    List<AcademicEntity> darrAcademy= new List<AcademicEntity>();

    CaafiContext caafi = new CaafiContext();
    List<Student> student = caafi.Student.ToList();

    var z = student.Find(student => student.intPkAcademy == 1);

    darrAcademy= caafi.AcademicEntity.ToList();
    
    var y = darrAcademy.Find(s => s.intPk == 1);

    servansdto = new ServansdtoServiceAnswerDto(200, student.ToList());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    servansdto= new ServansdtoServiceAnswerDto(400,ex.Message);
}

Estas son mis clases, Student, que hace referencia a la tabla 'Alumno', que tiene una llave foranea a la tabla 'OrganismoAcademico'. En esta he probado usar virtual en AcademicEntity, pero tampoco.
[Table("Alumno")]
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [Column("NumCta", TypeName = "varchar(12)")]
    public string strNmCta { get; set; }

    [Column("NomAlu", TypeName = "varchar(45)")]
    public string strName { get; set; }

    [Column("ApAlu", TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string strSurename { get; set; }

    [Column("Grado", TypeName = "varchar(40)")]
    public string strBachelors { get; set; }

    [Column("PkOrganismo")]
    [ForeignKey("AcademicEntity")]
    public int intPkAcademy { get; set; }

    public AcademicEntity AcademicEntity { get; set; } = new AcademicEntity();
}


Esta es la clase que hace referencia a la tabla OrganismoAcademico
[Table("OrganismoAcademico")]
public class AcademicEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Pk")]
    public int intPk { get; set; }

    [Column("Organismo", TypeName = "varchar(70)")]
    public string strAcademyName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; } = new List<Student>();
}

Y el context se ve mas o menos así:
    public CaafiContext(DbContextOptions<CaafiContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public CaafiContext()
    {   
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(strConectionString, 
            ServerVersion.AutoDetect(strConectionString));
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AcademicEntity>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Student)
            .WithOne(s => s.AcademicEntity)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.intPkAcademy)
            .HasPrincipalKey(s => s.intPk);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Workshop> Workshop { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tutor> Tutor { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AcademicEntity> AcademicEntity { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Material> Material { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Admin> Admin { get; set; }
}

En el he probado varias cosas, como definir de otra manera la relación entre tablas,
a veces incluyendo los dos pero no funciona.
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
.HasOne(s => s.AcademicEntity)
.WithMany(a => a.Student)
.HasForeignKey(s => s.intPkAcademy);

Me falta algo? O hay algo que este haciendo de manera incorrecta?

Parece que te falta habilitar la carga de relaciones entre las entidades al trabajar con Entity Framework. Por defecto, EF Core no carga las propiedades de navegación de forma automática. Debes usar carga explícita o carga ansiosa para que la propiedad de navegación AcademicEntity se cargue junto con Student.
 // Utilizar Include para cargar la relación
    List<Student> students = caafi.Student
                                  .Include(s => s.AcademicEntity)
                                  .ToList();

